# Remove space between mobile number odoo 13

Tags: mobile, format, space, odoo-13

I want to remove space and '-' between the mobile number in odoo v13. Currently my mobile number format like this '+977 960-2582808'. From this format i want to remove space and  '-'. This is mobile field in res.partner table with widget="phone".

expected result: +9779602582808

*I am trying below code:*

```
login_mobile = fields.Char()
mobile_sanitized = fields.Char(string='Mobile Number')
   
@api.onchange("login_mobile")
def onchange_device_id(self):
    print('aaaaaaaaaaaaa')
    self.mobile_sanitized = self.login_mobile.strip(' ')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.strip() removes characters from beginning and end of the string.
EDIT
Use regular expression:

```py
import re
self.mobile_sanitized = re.sub('[^0-9+]','', self.login_mobile)
```

Comment: Thanks Paxmess its work.
but i need '+' from this sequence.

Comment: then you can use only regular expression variant